# How to challenge the edit reviewers?

Tags: discussion

I edited some answers either to fix bugs or refine the code. 
My edits were rejected with no reasonable reasons more than once.

e.g. answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069297/1145694
and edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15773680

The former way I used to solve this issue to create another answer other than editing the existing answer. Now I'm really frustrated. Is there a way to challenge the edit reviewers publicly and how?

UPDATE: for the question has been marked duplicated of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). Of course, it helped me to understand when to edit code, but I don't think they are totally the same. The original question should be "When sometimes the reviewers may be wrong(at least, the editor thinks so), what can he/she do to challenge their judgments?". The mark behavior assumed that every reviewers did correct judgments.

Comment: Rather than challenging the reviewers, perhaps you should find out [what you should and should not change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code?rq=1). Your edit falls into one of the "should not" categories.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for your information, maybe you're right.

Comment: Don't change code in answers. If you believe the code has a few syntax issues then advise the author. If it's fundamentally wrong then provide a new answer.

Comment: @Bugs: No, changing code in answers is fine, same as changing *anything* in an answer *anywhere on SE*. You just have to make sure it doesn't change the author's intent, which usually means only small changes. Typo fixes are fine, as long as they're justified and fixing a clearly tangential mistake (as opposed to a mistaken post).

Comment: @NathanTuggy personally I would only make code changes once I had the full edit privileges and not if it goes through the edit review. My reasoning for that is reviewers don't need to have an understanding of the code. If they do, they would probably accept but chances are they won't and will reject. I don't like seeing free typed code so I'd copy into my IDE and make the necessary changes they copy back. It can look a bit change when reality it isn't.

Comment: @Bugs: That's not the worst of ideas, but I greatly dislike the meme of "don't edit code in answers". If reviewers aren't going to have the technical knowledge, add a comment with a detailed reasoning and allude to it in the edit summary.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I can't agree with you any more on "don't edit code in answers"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of [your suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145694/sunzhuoshi?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) involved substantive changes to code. For that reason, those edits were inappropriate. As explained in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346658/how-to-challenge-the-edit-reviewers#comment463275_346658), you should read the question and answers for [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code?rq=1).

In particular, you never want to change functionality or code style except for a truly obvious typo. For example, it's okay to change this

```
foo = bar
prinnt foo
```

to

```
foo = bar
print foo
```

in code that is supposed to be working. You wouldn't change that in the question if it's what caused the problem, or in an answer if it's somebody saying something like, "You have a typo in `prinnt foo`." It's also not okay to change it to something like

```
foo = bar
echo foo
```

or

```
Foo = Bar
print Foo
```

or

```
*foo = *bar
print *foo
```

In the example you gave, your edit changed the code significantly, and the reviewers were correct to reject it (those who did reject it, anyway). This is not really like Wikipedia, where everybody "cooks in the same pot" and it's okay to *completely* change what is there to make it better. You have to be careful to preserve the meaning of a post, including the logic of the code. (There are some exceptions to this, but nothing you need to worry about right now.)

We do appreciate that you want to make the site better! Thanks for asking here how you can improve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail explanation, especially the Wikipedia example. I know the rule here better now.

Comment: Of course if "prinnt foo" is the actual problem - don't change that :-)

Comment: @JonClements Good point. I meant in code in an answer that is supposed to work. I've clarified a bit.